# Python: Add index an index value to each array element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, knn

I'm trying to measure the precision and recall of a knn algorithm on the Iris dataset without using sklearn or something similar. My idea is to append both the predicted and the true values with an index, like that:

```
id = [i for i in range(1,len(np.asarray(y_pred))+1)]
y_pred_id = np.insert(y_pred, 0, id)
```

then delete all not Zeros, or not ones… and match the Indices to get the amount of TP. Sadly the Code I came up with only appends the Array in length, has anybody an idea on how to make the id stay that we have a Dimension of (n,2)?
EDIT: It would be great if one could do it without using a Pandas df.

Thanks in Advance,

Nikolas

Comment: can you give us sample input and output?

Comment: I could give you the whole knn algorithm I wrote before, but overall the resulting values will be something like:
'test = np.array((1,1,2,0,0,1,1,2))'

Comment: Sorry, of Course: `y_pred = np.array((1,1,2,0,0,1,1,2))`

Comment: And for the Output next to each element just the numbers of 0:7 (I don't know how to write a Vector here, sry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also construct a confusion matrix right away, instead of adding indices. For Example:

```
>>> preds = np.random.randint(0,3,size=(10,))
>>> truth = np.random.randint(0,3,size=(10,))
>>> preds
array([0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
>>> truth
array([0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2])
>>> n =len( np.unique(truth))
>>> c_m = np.zeros((n,n))
>>> for i in range(len(truth_arr)):
...     c_m[truth[i],preds[i]] += 1
... 
>>> c_m = c_m.T
>>> c_m
array([[2., 0., 2.],
       [1., 0., 1.],
       [2., 1., 1.]])
# At this point you can calculate your metrics
>>> recall_0_class = c_m[0,0]/c_m[:,0].sum()
>>> recall_0_class
0.4
```

Comment: This is a so much better idea of how to do it then I had, great! Not excactly the answer to the Question I had above, but if somebody has the same bigger issue, thats the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, you want an `n x 2` size matrix after inserting `id` to `y_pred`. If so, you can do it in following ways:

Option-1:
Use [np.reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

```
...
y_pred_id = np.insert(y_pred, 0, id)
y_pred_id.reshape(2, n)  # you should define 'n' somewhere, maybe use len(id)!

Output:
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2]])
```

Options-2:
Use [np.vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)

```
...
y_pred_id = np.vstack([y_pred, id])

Output:
array([[1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Comment: Yeah, you got me Right. But won't that Code result in an `2xn` Matrix and if I Change it to `y_pred_id.reshape(n,2)` mix up my `id` and `y_pred` values?

Comment: You could take a transpose afterwards. So, something like: `reshape(2, n).T`

Comment: Haha just thought of it, you're rigth it works perfect that way. Thanks a lot dvlper!